# issue using smart gwt 3.0 with minor changes to a sample from showcase

Tags: smartgwt, gwt2

I am using Smart GWT 3.0- specifically I am working with the rotate sample that uses drawing class.

I have changed the triangle drawn, and instead want to show a image in its place- I want this image to rotate in the same way as the other shapes are rotated when the user clicks on slider ( as shown in showcase)

There is no error shown in eclipse after I have modified the code and saved it.

I have changed the triangle shape code and replaced it with the following--

```
           DrawImage drawImg= new DrawImage();
           drawImg.setSrc("other/earth.png");
           drawImg.setDrawPane(drawPane);  
           drawImg.setLeft(100);
           drawImg.setHeight(100);
           drawImg.draw();
```

However an "Uncaught Exception" error is shown when I run GWT Dev mode and try to see the html page containing the drawings.

Given below is the error I get in Google Chrome when the app fails to run--

```
onModuleLoad() threw an exception
Exception while loading module com.arvindikchari.bspinner.client.Spinner. See Development Mode for details.

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:396)
at     
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:200)
at 

     com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:525)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:363)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError): Cannot call method 'create' of undefined
at     
  com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:248)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:269)
at 
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
at com.smartgwt.client.widgets.drawing.DrawPane.create(DrawPane.java)
at com.smartgwt.client.widgets.BaseWidget.getOrCreateJsObj(BaseWidget.java:361)
at com.smartgwt.client.widgets.layout.Layout.addMember(Layout.java:1153)
at com.arvindikchari.bspinner.client.Spinner.onModuleLoad(Spinner.java:244)
... 9 more
```

UPDATE--

Error occurs at line 244 of onModuleLoad-- code at this line is given below--

```
layout.addMember(drawPane);
```

The error occurs due to code of onModuleLoad-- the entire code for this is now given below--

```
 public void onModuleLoad() {  
        drawPane = new DrawPane();  
        drawPane.setHeight(450);  
        drawPane.setWidth(700);  
        drawPane.setLeft(25);  
        drawPane.setShowEdges(true);  
        drawPane.setEdgeSize(4);  
        drawPane.setBackgroundColor("papayawhip");  
        drawPane.setOverflow(Overflow.HIDDEN);  
        drawPane.setCursor(Cursor.AUTO);  

        drawPane.addDrawHandler(new DrawHandler() {  

        @Override  
        public void onDraw(DrawEvent event) {  

            DrawPane drawPane = (DrawPane) event.getSource();  

            DrawLabel imglabel= new DrawLabel();


           DrawImage drawImg= new DrawImage();
           drawImg.setSrc("other/earth.png");
           drawImg.setDrawPane(drawPane);  
           drawImg.setLeft(100);
           drawImg.setHeight(100);
           drawImg.draw();


            DrawLabel curveLabel = new DrawLabel();  
            curveLabel.setDrawPane(drawPane);  
            curveLabel.setLeft(200);  
            curveLabel.setTop(175);  
            curveLabel.setContents("Curve");  
            curveLabel.draw();  

            DrawCurve drawCurve = new DrawCurve();  
            drawCurve.setDrawPane(drawPane);  
            drawCurve.setStartPoint(new Point(200,50));  
            drawCurve.setEndPoint(new Point(300,150));  
            drawCurve.setControlPoint1(new Point(250,0));  
            drawCurve.setControlPoint2(new Point(250,200));  
            drawCurve.draw();  

            DrawLabel linePathLabel = new DrawLabel();  
            linePathLabel.setDrawPane(drawPane);  
            linePathLabel.setLeft(350);  
            linePathLabel.setTop(175);  
            linePathLabel.setContents("Line Path");  
            linePathLabel.draw();  

            DrawLinePath drawLinePath = new DrawLinePath();  
            drawLinePath.setDrawPane(drawPane);  
            drawLinePath.setStartPoint(new Point(350,50));  
            drawLinePath.setEndPoint(new Point(450,150));  
            drawLinePath.draw();  

            DrawLabel pathLabel = new DrawLabel();  
            pathLabel.setDrawPane(drawPane);  
            pathLabel.setLeft(500);  
            pathLabel.setTop(175);  
            pathLabel.setContents("Path");  
            pathLabel.draw();  

            DrawPath drawPath = new DrawPath();  
            drawPath.setDrawPane(drawPane);  
            drawPath.setPoints(  
                    new Point(500,50),  
                    new Point(525,50),  
                    new Point(550,75),  
                    new Point(575,75),  
                    new Point(600,75),  
                    new Point(600,125),  
                    new Point(575,125),  
                    new Point(550,125),  
                    new Point(525,150),  
                    new Point(500,150)  
            );  
            drawPath.draw();  

            DrawLabel ovalLabel = new DrawLabel();  
            ovalLabel.setDrawPane(drawPane);  
            ovalLabel.setLeft(50);  
            ovalLabel.setTop(415);  
            ovalLabel.setContents("Oval");  
            ovalLabel.draw();  

            DrawOval drawOval = new DrawOval();  
            drawOval.setDrawPane(drawPane);  
            drawOval.setLeft(50);  
            drawOval.setTop(300);  
            drawOval.setWidth(100);  
            drawOval.setHeight(100);  
            drawOval.draw();  

            DrawLabel rectLabel = new DrawLabel();  
            rectLabel.setDrawPane(drawPane);  
            rectLabel.setLeft(200);  
            rectLabel.setTop(415);  
            rectLabel.setContents("Rect");  
            rectLabel.draw();  

            DrawRect drawRect = new DrawRect();  
            drawRect.setDrawPane(drawPane);  
            drawRect.setLeft(200);  
            drawRect.setTop(300);  
            drawRect.setWidth(150);  
            drawRect.setHeight(100);  
            drawRect.draw();  

            DrawLabel lineLabel = new DrawLabel();  
            lineLabel.setDrawPane(drawPane);  
            lineLabel.setLeft(400);  
            lineLabel.setTop(415);  
            lineLabel.setContents("Line");  
            lineLabel.draw();  

            DrawLine drawLine = new DrawLine();  
            drawLine.setDrawPane(drawPane);  
            drawLine.setStartPoint(new Point(400,300));  
            drawLine.setEndPoint(new Point(500,400));  
            drawLine.draw();  

            DrawLabel sectorLabel = new DrawLabel();  
            sectorLabel.setDrawPane(drawPane);  
            sectorLabel.setLeft(550);  
            sectorLabel.setTop(415);  
            sectorLabel.setContents("Sector");  
            sectorLabel.draw();  

            DrawSector drawSector = new DrawSector();  
            drawSector.setDrawPane(drawPane);  
            drawSector.setCenterPoint(new Point(550,300));  
            drawSector.setStartAngle(0);  
            drawSector.setEndAngle(90);  
            drawSector.setRadius(100);  
            drawSector.draw();  

        }  
    });  

    ValueChangedHandler shapeRotationSliderValueChangeHandler = new      ValueChangedHandler() {  
        @Override  
        public void onValueChanged(ValueChangedEvent event) {  
            DrawItem[] drawItems = drawPane.getDrawItems();  
            for (int i = 0; i < drawItems.length; i++) {  
                DrawItem drawItem = drawItems[i];  
                if(drawItem instanceof DrawLabel){  
                    continue;  
                }  
                drawItem.rotateTo(event.getValue());  
            }  
            drawPane.redraw();  
        }  
    };  

    Slider shapesRotationSlider = new Slider();  
    shapesRotationSlider.setMinValue(0);  
    shapesRotationSlider.setMaxValue(360);  
    shapesRotationSlider.setNumValues(360);  
    shapesRotationSlider.setWidth(400);  
    shapesRotationSlider.setLeft(25);  
    shapesRotationSlider.setTop(450);  
    shapesRotationSlider.setValue(0);  
    shapesRotationSlider.setTitle("Rotate Shapes");  
    shapesRotationSlider.setVertical(false);  
    shapesRotationSlider.addValueChangedHandler(shapeRotationSliderValueChangeHandler);  
    shapesRotationSlider.draw();  

    VLayout layout = new VLayout();  
    layout.addMember(drawPane);  
    layout.addMember(shapesRotationSlider);  
    layout.draw();  


    layout.draw();  
}
```

Comment: @AdelBoutros - no i could not solve it- but I could not spend much time on it because of other work :(

Answer (score 1):

First of all the `UmbrellaException` is a wrapper of the true exception shown at the "**caused by**" line

So your real exception is :

> Caused by: com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException:
>   (TypeError): Cannot call method 'create' of undefined

If you scroll below it, you would see the error is caused when calling the `onModuleLoad` in your **Spinner.java** at the line **244**:

> com.arvindikchari.bspinner.client.Spinner.onModuleLoad(Spinner.java:244)

So try to find out what's wrong, if you can't solve it, then please post the entire code of the `onModuleLoad` method.

### UPDATE:

**You have many problems:**

The `onValueChanged` of `shapeRotationSliderValueChangeHandler` is being called before the layout is drawn. To solve this, add a `private boolean firstTime = true` and in the `onValueChanged` add this :

```
if (firstTime) {
    firstTime = false;
} else {
    DrawItem[] drawItems = drawPane.getDrawItems();  
    for (int i = 0; i < drawItems.length; i++) {  
        DrawItem drawItem = drawItems[i];  
        if(drawItem instanceof DrawLabel){  
            continue;  
        }  
        drawItem.rotateTo(event.getValue());  
    }  
    drawPane.redraw(); 
}
```

**PS:** For the other problems which i coulnd't solve, please recheck your entire code for things similar to the one above.

Comment: @AdelBoutros- I have updated the question with the code from my onModuleLoad...pls take a look... thanks

Comment: @AdelBoutros- the code is straight from the Smart GWT showcase, and I have only replaced a triangle with an image... I can make sense of what you are saying though... I will look into this as per your advice...

Comment: @Arvind can you please provide the link to the smartGWT example in the showcase?

Answer (score 1):

First check GWT Xml file have following inherits above the " entry class " line.

```
<inherits name="com.smartgwt.Drawing"/>;
```

also add following line in your java file

```
import com.smartgwt.*;
```